# asp.net core 3 routing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

In my Asp.net core 3 project I am using some controler to access from js code to do some stuff and also using Razor pages at the same time.

at the configure service section :

```
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
```

I added both RazorPages and MVC controller with view.

And at then configure section

```
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {              
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

Added above codes.
When I try to access to controller I am getting 404. I also tried to add just `services.AddControllers();`

need help please.

Edit : controller code

```
public class DashboardsController : BaseController, IDashboardsController
{
    [HttpGet]
     public async Task<JsonResult> GetAssetCategorySummaryAsync(){
        -------
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you attempting? What does the controller look like?

Comment: GET http://localhost:9011/Dashboards/GetAssetCategorySummaryAsync 404 (Not Found)
it's the URL I am trying.
and the controller

public class DashboardsController : BaseController, IDashboardsController
{
 [HttpGet]
  public async Task<JsonResult> GetAssetCategorySummaryAsync(){
  -------
 }
}

Comment: Update your question with the controller code. Can't read it in a comment.

Comment: sorry. added controller code

Comment: Try putting `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` after the `MapControllerRoute` in `app.UseEndpoints()`

Comment: no. nothing changed

Comment: Hi @S.AzizKazdal did you solve this issue? I have admin area (MVC) and identity area (RazorPages). But if I register RazorPages services, than it is breaking admin routing and I am getting 404 error for admin area actions.

Comment: yes I solved the issue. my problem was related to **SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames** one of breaking changes in net core 3. I am using below routing and it works fine for me
`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });`

Comment: @S.AzizKazdal thanks. I have solved my problem now. I added this to admin controller base: `[Area("Admin")]
    [Route("Admin/[controller]/[action]")]` for more info: https://developpaper.com/asp-net-core-3-0-area-and-routing-configuration-method/

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be `localhost:9011/Dashboards/GetAssetCategorySummary`.

You could modify the Startup.cs like below to allow using the whole action name:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false;
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

It is a known issue on github,you could refer to [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8998).

Comment: thank you. another breaking change in asp.net core 3
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/351

Comment: I have already did it. thank you again. Bu I did no change the URL change adden options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend my solution.

In Startup

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Create your CUSTOM base controller like that.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{id?}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomBaseController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

And use CustomBaseController

```
 public class TestController : CustomBaseController
    {
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok($"Test {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        }
    }
```

Rout` **api/Test/test**